# onclick="location.href='manaliPackages.html'" not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to link my button with another page. I am using the code given below to do so.

```
<button type="button" value="button text" class="commonBtn" 
onclick="location.href='manaliPackages.html'";> View Variations</button>
```

But it is not working... Why not?

Comment: Do you have another page called `manaliPackages.html` in the same folder? "it is not working" what is it doing?

Comment: Please press F12 and look in the console and  network tab to see why

Comment: @balastrong its doing nothing... And yes I am Having it in the same folder.

Comment: @mplungjan I inspected and found that the onclick attribute is not showing there

Comment: Can you please provide [minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That code alone should work just fine. You said that it doesn't show in browser but you did make it in code editor? Can you please notify us if you're using localhost, maybe _XAMPP_ or you are using hosted website? Also, as I said in previous question, please provide minimal, reproducible example with code around.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine
*(I'm assuming manaliPackages.html is a file in the same directory as the html file holding your code.)*
For example:
 **link/to/your/html/file.html** contains the following:

```
<button type="button" value="button text" class="commonBtn" 
onclick="location.href='manaliPackages.html'";> View Variations</button>
```

Clicking this button would open: **link/to/your/html/manaliPackages.html**
Also, it is considered bad practice to use inline code, you should consider adding an event listener instead.
Please provide a snapshot of your browser console

Comment: yes I tried the exact same code and it works just fine

Comment: Yes, it should work alone. Check out my comment on his post.

Comment: the problems seems to be not code-related, it's probably a directory problem.

Comment: could be also host related. Sometimes XAMPP knows to not update code files or maybe if he is using FTP directly on hosted website

Comment: that's possible, also, yes. This could be due to a number of reasons. further details are required.

Comment: Indeed, needs more details.